# assertEquals throws a NullPointerException, but equals method does not

Tags: junit, nullpointerexception

I have two list objects and want to check that the first items of each are equal. However, I get a NullPointerException at this line:

```
assertEquals(instance.getPlane(0), planes.get(0));
```

This is the entire stack trace:

> Testcase: testGetPlane(mypackage.PlaneTest):  Caused an ERROR
>   null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at mypackage.PlaneTest.testGetPlane(PlaneTest.java:60)

(Line 60 is the assertion.)

Neither of those objects are null. I'm having a separate issue getting the debugger to work, so instead I added these printouts to my test case:

```
System.err.println("equals? " + instance.getPlane(0).equals(planes.get(0)));
System.err.println("equals? " + planes.get(0).equals(instance.getPlane(0)));
```

However, those lines executed without throwing any errors!

I've cleaned and built the project and restarted Netbeans, but still have this issue.

JUnit just calls `expected.equals(actual)`, which should be exactly the same thing as my printouts that aren't throwing the error, right? Why would `assertEquals` throw a NullPointerException, but `equals` on the same objects would not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I was about to post the question alone when I discovered the fix, but since it was a pain I'm posting it anyways in hopes this may help someone else. I did not find any other questions which had this solution.)

The error is in fact caused by JUnit, when it tries to compose an error message.

In [the `format` function](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java#L838), there are the lines:

```
String expectedString = String.valueOf(expected);
String actualString = String.valueOf(actual);
if (expectedString.equals(actualString)) { ... }
```

[String.valueOf(Object obj)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) returns `obj.toString()` if `obj` is not null.

My object's `toString` method simply returned a "name" field, which was never set inside the test. So, the object was not null, but the function returned null. This caused the NullPointerException when JUnit tried to call `expectedString.equals`. Ensuring that `toString` never returns null fixed the error.